# Optimal fitting of spheres in a cylinder

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, sphere-packing

How to find the minimum height and width of a cylinder containing n identical spheres?

Comment: I misjudged this question. As asked, it is trivial, but Joseph O'Rourke's answer indicates that there is an interesting question in the background.

Comment: See the literature on "the sausage conjecture".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a 2012 paper whose references 
(and its now [Aug 2017] 26 [subsequent citations](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=2260076989103249441&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=0,22&hl=en)) will lead you to literature on this topic:

> A. Mughal, H. K. Chan, D. Weaire, and S. Hutzler.
>   "Dense packings of spheres in cylinders: Simulations"
>   *Phys. Rev. E* 85, 051305 (2012).
>   ([Journal link](http://pre.aps.org/abstract/PRE/v85/i5/e051305))

---

[image: SpheresInCylinder]

---

Comment: Another recent reference for simulation is L. Fu, William Steinhardt,   H. Zhao, J.E.S. Socolarb and   P. Charbonneau  "Hard sphere packings within cylinders" _Soft Matter_, 2016,**12**, 2505-2514 [journal link](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2016/sm/c5sm02875b#!divAbstract)